# Amazon EC2 To External Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb, iptables, rds

I have started working on a new project. I have a requirement to connect to a remote MariaDB database that is not hosted on AWS from an Amazon EC2 instance.

I have root access to the database but it is fairly locked down.
I need to ssh into a Linux machine, sudo as the root user and then connect to the Maria DB instance which is fine

Now I am trying to connect to it from an EC2 instance using the mysql command.
I created a user on the MariaDB instance with access from localhost and anywhere

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Unfortunately that does not work.
I checked the IP tables on the MariaDB instance and they are empty.

Is there anything else I can try so that I can connect to this database?

**Update**
Tried the following iptables and still no joy

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
```

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Mysql needs to connect on port 3306 to the db server. Is that port open in your firewall to allow the ec2 instance public ip access to db.

Comment: @MisterSmith - I checked the iptables on the linux server that hosts the db and they are empty

Comment: Where is db hosted? Do you have a web dashboard for the hosting? If so I would guess there's a firewall of some description in there?

Comment: It is hosted on a customers site. I can shoot them a note and ask to see.

Comment: You need to show us the actual error.  Without that, it's all guesswork.

Comment: There is no error. If i try to use mysql to connect it ends up hanging

Comment: I'll hedge my bets and guess your customers site will have a firewall. I'd suggest you attach an elastic ip to the instance(it can be attached to any instance without a firewall change in the future). Then request they allow your elastic ip through there firewall.

Comment: @MisterSmith - they are running on rackspace - would there possibly be any other firewall bar iptables that they may be using? I updated the question with the current iptables that I am using

Comment: Backspace will definitely have a firewall (accessed via their control panel).

Comment: @MisterSmith the server is not a managed server - could there still be something in the control panel stopping connections? Apologies - I am not too familiar with Rackspace and I dont have access

Comment: Rackspaces provide a firewall for all hosting.  https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/firewall-manager-v2/

Answer (score 1):

It is quite normal for databases to be secured such that they are not accessible from the internet. This is good security practice.

A common method of connecting to a database in this situation (for administration or DBA access, not for application access) is to use **ssh with port forwarding**.

You could login in via ssh with an additional parameter that forwards a local port to the remote port. You did not specify an OS, but here's how you would do it on Linux/Mac:

```
ssh user@hostname -L 8306:DB-DNS:3306
```

You would then connect to the database on: `localhost:8306`

- `8306` can be any number. It just specifies the local port to be forwarded
- `DB-DNS` would be the DNS name of the database server to which you are connecting *from the Jump Box that you're SSHing into*. If the database is on that remote box you're connecting to, then just use `localhost`
- `3306` is the database port you are connecting to

So, it effectively says "anything sent to port 8306 on my computer should be forwarded to the remote machine and then be sent to DB-DNS:3306".

Se: [SSH port forwarding - Example, command, server config | SSH.COM](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example)

Answer (score 1):

Damien. Based on your comments the issue is almost certainly rackspaces firewall. Your client should be able to edit the firewall via rackspaces web console or log a support ticket.

I'd strongly suggest you use an elastic ip you attach to the instance and not the default public ip of the instance. This is for your convenience / is just a good idea (in case you loose the ip by stopping/starting instance etc.)